# Laravel 8 same route multiple middleware using OR condition

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

Hello i tried to use middleware like the code below to validate OR operator

```
Route::get('/page', [Controller::class, 'index'])->middleware(['mid1','mid2']);
```

in this example it uses the AND operator not OR I used also groups like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'mid1'], function () {
   Route::get('/page', [Controller::class, 'index']);
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'mid2'], function () {
   Route::get('/page', [Controller::class, 'index']);
});
```

but using groups with same route the second route in the group is the only one readable.
Any help please

Comment: What do you want to do in mid1 and mid2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing builtin in laravel to do such a thing.

You can create another middle-ware to contain both conditions you need to apply.

In you middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (condition1 || condition2) {
       return $request($next);
    }
    abort('statusCode');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Faesal. It would be best to combine two middleware logic into one middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (your condition) {
       //logic inside mid1 handler
    }else{
       //logic inside mid2 handler
    }
}
```

Although it is not recommended but you can put your conditions in route file.

```
if(your conditions){
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'mid1'], function () {
   Route::get('/page', [Controller::class, 'index']);
  });
}else{
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'mid2'], function () {
   Route::get('/page', [Controller::class, 'index']);
  });
}
```